# Largest Permutation in k steps (R)

Tags: r, algorithm, permutation, greedy

I have a problem where I would like to replace 2 numbers in a set upto "k"-times such that each time they are switched, I get the largest possible permutation and print this after k-swaps. For example with  k=2, for the set (1,4,2,5,3,3) in 1 step I would swap (1,5) to create (5,4,2,1,3,3). In step 2 I would swap (2,3) to create (5,4,3,1,3,2). If after the n <  k(th) point we already have the largest permutation e.g. (5,4,3,3,2,1) then we stop.

So far this is what I have:

```
x<-y<-c(1,4,2,5,3,3)
sx<-sort(x,decreasing=TRUE)
if(k>=n){cat(sx)} else{ ### If we have more operations than numbers?
i<-0; k<-2
m<-max(y)
while(i<k){
  if(all(sort(x,decreasing=TRUE)==y)){break}
  i<-i+1
  a<-max(which(y==m))
  while(length(which(y[c(1:a)]<m))==0){
    m<-m-1
    a<-which(y==m) ### Location of the largest number
    if(length(a)==0){
      a<-1
      next
    }
    a<-max(a)
  }
  y[c(min(which(y[c(1:a)]<m)),a)]<-y[c(a,min(which(y[c(1:a)]<m)))]
}
cat(y)
}
5 4 2 1 3 3
```

Essentially the code finds the max of the current set. Then finds the right most occurrence of this max number. Then finds the left most number lower than the max number. Then switches them. This continues until we have performed k steps OR we have the largest permutation before k. Then prints it.

This code works but takes too long if there are more than 10^4 digits for large k. Is there a way to reduce complexity to O(n) in R?

Comment: Perhaps you should pose this question in a site with a higher concentration of minds who think algorithmically? That might inform the R-implementation question.

Comment: Why from here, (5,4,2,1,3,3), didn't you swap 2 and the rightmost 3 to create (5,4,3,1,3,2), which is a higher permutation than (5,4,3,1,2,3)?

Comment: You are correct. That is what I meant and is what my code does! I shall edit that.

Comment: Isn't it a bubble sort?

Comment: I feel like there is a faster method. Perhaps in Python or C (not that I know much) but R seems slow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `O(n log n)`-time algorithm (`O(n)` is impossible with comparisons only, though maybe you know something about the input numbers).

For each subarray of the permutation having (zero-indexed) bounds `[i 2^j, (i+1) 2^j)` for some integers `i, j`, store the minimum and the maximum value in the subarray (i.e., set up a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) structure).

To find the maximum in an interval in time `O(log n)`, decompose the interval into `O(log n)` elementary intervals and return the maximum of the maximums.

To find the rightmost maximum in an elementary interval in time `O(log n)`, repeatedly descend to the right child if its maximum is equal to the target, else descend to the left child.

To find the leftmost number lower than a target number in an interval in time `O(log n)`, decompose the interval into `O(log n)` elementary intervals and find the leftmost elementary interval whose minimum is lower than the target. From this interval, repeatedly descend to the left child if its minimum is lower than the target, else the descend to the right child.

Following your example:

```
        1,5
  4,5         1,2         3,3
5     4     2     1     3     3
```

We just moved `5`, and `4` is in the right place, so we want the maximum on the rest of the array. The elementary intervals are `2 1` and `3 3`. The maximum is `3`. We examine `3 3` and discover that the maximum is in the right child, all the way at the end.

Now we seek the leftmost number less than `3`. The elementary intervals are `2 1` and `3 3`. We see that `2 1` has a minimum less than `3`, so we examine it. So does the left child of `2 1`, so `2` is what we swap `3` with.

```
       *1,5*
  4,5        *1,2*       *3,3*
5     4     3     1     3     2
```

The aggregates in `*asterisks*` may need updating (ancestors of the swapped values). There are `O(log n)` of these. We work bottom up.

```
       *1,5*
  4,5         1,3        *3,3*
5     4     3     1     3     2

        1,5
  4,5         1,3        *3,3*
5     4     3     1     3     2

        1,5
  4,5         1,3         2,3
5     4     3     1     3     2
```

Comment: I think I see where this is going although I am not 100% grasping the child concept. So setup a vector such that the endpoints of each partition form the lowest to highest maximum number. Then after an O(n logn) search, we can always descend if this minimum is lower than the target?

Comment: @TonyHellmuth Added an example.